# ASP.NET MVC 3, Ajax.BeginForm, OnBegin and form validation

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Ajax.BeginForm and wish to pass in parameters to the function called with OnBegin. The following are two code snippets.

```
new AjaxOptions
{
   HttpMethod = "POST",
   UpdateTargetId = "DataEntrySummary",                
   OnBegin = "ValidateForm(11,55)"
}

function ValidateForm(minAge, maxAge) {return false;}
```

The parameters are passed in correctly to the ValidateForm function but the function always returns true.

If I take the parameters out and use

```
OnBegin = "ValidateForm()"
function ValidateForm() {return false;}
```

It works perfectly and returns false. Am I missing something or are parameters not allowed here or ...

Puzzled of Oxford - thanks in advance.

PS - I cannot use C# Attributes and Unobtrusive validation for very good reasons (these *are* code snippets).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043765/modify-posted-input-values-on-onbegin-of-ajax-beginform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the comment from CrazyCoderz relates, but it is linked some how.

What I have found is that anything after the the function name causes the Ajax OBegin to return true. This includes OnBegin = "ValidateForm()". [My error above on the brackets]

I am now implementing a 'work around' - one of two - either write my own Ajax call *or* read the attributes from the test input element of the form to get the values I want. So, thanks CrazyCoderz for putting me on the track to a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
OnBegin = "return ValidateForm(11,55)"

function ValidateForm(a,b) {
    return a<b;
}
```