# onBegin function to unmask form field works but value is sent to controller still with mask

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that is sent using Ajax.

There is a field with a mask and its value looks like this: (This field is added dinamically)

```
(011) 1111-1111
```

I have a beforeSend callback function that removes the mask.

I can see the field just before the form is sent:

```
01111111111
```

But in my controller I am getting the value as if I am not removing the mask. Cannot understand why!

**Form**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("opImportFile", "Operacao", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "validation", OnSuccess = "LimparCampos", OnFailure = "LimparCampos" }, new { id = "formUpdStoringSettings" }))
{
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Importação - Arquivo</legend>
        <!--    <h2><a href="#" id="AddAbsPath" class="editBtn" onclick="addArmazenamento();" style="font-size:12px; color:#E17009 !important;"> Adicionar</a></h2>            -->
        <table id="tblArmazenamento">            
                <tr id="@element">                           
                    <td>@Html.Hidden("idCaminhoRepositorio_" + element)
                        @Html.TextBox("caminhorepositorio_" + element, "", new { @class = "validate[required] smallField limpar", disabled = "disabled" })
                        @Html.Hidden("caminhoRepositorio_" + element, "", new { @class = "validate[required] smallField limpar"})</td>
                    <td><a href="#" id="editPath" class="editBtn" onclick="FileTree()"> Localizar</a>
                        <a href="#" id="RemAbsPath_@element" class="editBtn" onclick="removeArmazenamento(@element);" style="color:red !important;"> Remover</a>
                    </td>    
                </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.tipo, new SelectList(Model.tipo, "idTipo", "nomeTipo"), "Escolha um Tipo", new { @class = "validate[required] smallField" })</td></tr>             
            <tr><td colspan="2"><br /></td></tr>
        </table><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Importar" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only button-link" />                    
        </fieldset>         
}
```

**callback**

```
function validation() {
    $('.mask').each(function (index) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace('(', ''));
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(')', ''));
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/-/g, ''));
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g, ''));
        $(this).text($(this).val()); //Here I get an unmaked value
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
string[] indicesValues = form["group"].Split(','); //Here I am getting a masked value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar issue posted here:

[Modify posted input values on onbegin of ajax.beginform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043765/modify-posted-input-values-on-onbegin-of-ajax-beginform)

Essentially, the values you are modifying on the form are not the values that have already been serialized by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting based on the "mask" class to remove the mask, but I do not see any controls with that class.  Are you missing a class on your input? I believe your last line of javascript should also be .val instead of .text.