# Ajax.BeginForm onBegin does not set values

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I haven't found it out ... yet.

I have a view in MVC with an Ajax.BeginForm. The model has a property Value (string). This is a part of the view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "TheController", new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "Target",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    LoadingElementId = "loader",
    OnBegin = "SetValues()"
})) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Value)

    <label>A label</label>
    <input type="text" id="anInt"/>
    <select id="aMeasurement">
        <option value="px">PX</option>
        <option value="%">%</option>
        <option value="em">em</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit it"/>
}
```

The function SetValues:

```
function SetValues(){
    $("#Value").val($("#anInt").val() + $("#aMeasurement").val())
}
```

This should set, for example, 100px in the hiddenfield "Value".

When submitting the forum, I expect the field "Value" to become a combination of anInt and aMeasurement, but it isn't. I use Chrome and when I inspect the elements I see the correct value set in the hidden element "Value", but when I debug the controller, the Value is empty.

When I debug the JS I see that the function SetValues is called and I also see the correct value is set in the Value-element. After the JS function is completed Visual Studio breaks on the the breakpoint on the correct method in the controller.

I cannot seem to figure out why this isn't working. Or maybe I'm dealing with this the wrong way.

Anyone knows how to do this or has a better idea?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to ryanulit and Scott MacMaster, I came up with this:

I added an ID to the form and added this little JS script:

```
$(function(){
    $("ID_OR_NAME_FORM").submit(function () {
        ... Do stuff
    });
});
```

As soon as the form is submitted (and before sending data to the controller) the submit-function in Javascript is called. This will set the correct values for me and then post data to the controller.

Comment: Did you try OnBegin = "SetValues" without the "()"?

Comment: Yes, but same result. The Javascript function is called by the way (updated in original post)

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this problem is very simple:

```
$("#Form_Id_You_Have_To_Change").on("submit", function () { SetValues(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant this

```
function SetValues(){
    $("#Value").val($("#anInt").val() + $("#aMeasurement").val())
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this is just an example. To post the complete code would scare people away :). I have changed the original post

Comment: I usually use jquery instead of the ajax extensions.  However, the documentation for OnBegin() says 'Gets or sets the name of the JavaScript function to call immediately before the page is updated.'  This isn't clear as this doesn't say if this happens before of after the post.  Maybe don't use OnBegin and instead add "onclick='return SetValues();'" to the submit control.  You could also put "alert('Hi');" in your function to see when it's called.  Or use "debugger;" to invoke the debugger if you find that preferable.

Comment: This is what I was think too. Documentation on this is not ... very good. It could go both ways. Anyway, I will try your idea a.s.a.p and let you know. I personally like to stick to the ajax extensions, but if there is no other wat to accomplish this....

Comment: As @ScottMacMaster has said, the AjaxOptions class does not allow any method for you to update the value before submit.  You will need to bind to the onclick event of the submit button, or to the form submit event and change the value there.  Here are some examples to help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043765/modify-posted-input-values-on-onbegin-of-ajax-beginform and http://www.codemonkeycode.net/index.php/2011/02/set-property-mvc-model-with-jquery-ajax-beginform/

Comment: Thanks people. See my original post. I've added the solution there. Seems to work like it should now, with the Ajax form and some minor Javascript addings.